# shell script meaning

Tags: bash, shell

eI want to understand what is the issue with this process; it's not giving the count back when the one process is running. It is directly going in to echo **"No QMS process found running on $PWD"** this condition.

```
QMS_PROCESS=`ps -ef | grep $PWD/qms_kernel | grep -v grep | cut -f6 -d' '`
QMS_PROCESS_COUNT=`echo $QMS_PROCESS | egrep [0-9] | wc -c`
if [ $QMS_PROCESS_COUNT -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "No QMS process found running on $PWD" 
  else
    kill -15 $QMS_PROCESS
    echo "QMS process $QMS_PROCESS stopped on $PWD" 
fi
```

can any one please help me understanding in this.

Comment: When you run `ps -ef | grep $PWD/qms_kernel | grep -v grep | cut -f6 -d' '` manually, do you see the line you expect?

Comment: Thanks for you response. I run manually but its not showing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this approach:

```
QMS_PROCESS=`pidof "$PWD/qms_kernel"`
if [ -z "$QMS_PROCESS" ]; then
  echo "No QMS process found running on $PWD" 
else
  kill -15 $QMS_PROCESS
  echo "QMS process ($QMS_PROCESS) stopped on $PWD" 
fi
```

Comment: thanks for your response JoaaMorais but i can change the script. I was just trying to understand the script.

Comment: Hello @user1771540. First line takes the PID of all "$PWD/qms_kernel" process, separated with spaces, and save them into QMS_PROCESS var. If there isn't a single process (-z means "empty string"), go to "No QMS..." branch, otherwise kill all found process.

Answer (score 0):

The first line runs `ps -ef` to list all processes, looks for a particular `qms_kernel` process with the path to the current directory in front of it (that's the `$PWD` part, and it is a bit surprising), then filters out the `grep` command and runs an arcane `cut` command to collect the 6th field.

The second line counts the number of digits, which is also a trifle odd.

The `if` block checks whether the value in `$QMS_PROCESS_COUNT` is 0 or not.  If it is, it reports 'No QMS process` and otherwise attempts to terminate (signal 15, aka TERM or SIGTERM) the process(es) and reports that the processes were stopped.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm looking for this answer. that qms_kernel has some working but that cut -f6 -d' ' is collecting the 6th field which is making some problem. Im new to my project and I dont know much about the what qms_kernel does. anyways itleast I understood whats happening in this script. Thanks Jonathan :)

Comment: Jonathan - actually whats happening is I was trying to stop the process and update the data to that process and trying to start the process. Some how its not stopping the process and but i killed the process manually by using kill -15 'process id running'. But when i'm updating its the data which i'm trying to update is moving to the location im expecting but when im starting the process again, its not taking the new data. i can check this data thru mainframe application but its not showing up there. Its showing previous data only. Can you help me where can be the problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: On my systems, the PID (which is what you need to kill a process) is in field 2 of the output from `ps -ef`, not field 6 (`cut -i -d' ' -f2`).  Use `bash -x script` to see what your script is executing.  Don't run `kill` commands until you're confident it will send the right signal to the right process (use `echo kill -15 $QMS_PROCESS` to see what it would do, for example).